# Magento2 error giving call to member function on null when declare View Model for product/view/addtocart.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, viewmodel

1.catalog_product_view.xml inside custom theme Magento_Catalog folder

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel</argument>
         </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

2. Calling in product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
    /* @var $viewModel Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel */
    
    $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
    
    echo $viewModel->getTitle();
```

3. View Model File

```
namespace Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel;

class OversizeViewModel implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more blocks using `Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml`, but you haven't declared `view_model` so you get this error.

To find which blocks using this phtml file, find "Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml" in **vendor/magento** directory.

There are 4 blocks in 3 layout files using this phtml: Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml, Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml, and Magento_Wishlist/layout/wishlist_index_configure_type_bundle.xml.

Finaly, to use View Model in `Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml`, you have to declare `view_model` to 4 blocks:

- `app/theme/<Vendor>/<themeName>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel</argument>
     </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel</argument>
     </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

- `app/theme/<Vendor>/<themeName>/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.bundle">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel</argument>
     </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

- `app/theme/<Vendor>/<themeName>/Magento_Wishlist/layout/wishlist_index_configure_type_bundle.xml`:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.bundle">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel</argument>
     </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Don't forget to clear cache (layout type) after making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you've added the view model in one block but other areas used this template. So Instead of adding the view model in the blocks argument in the layout, we can add the view model to the block in the **.php** files using plugins as below.

In your case we need to add the before plugin for '**\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php**'

Declare the plugin **di.xml** in the **app/code/Tavant/Catalog/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View">
        <plugin name="adding_view_model" type="Tavant\Catalog\Plugin\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The plugin **view.php** as **app/code/Tavant/Catalog/Plugin/View.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Tavant\Catalog\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View as Subject;
use Tavant\Catalog\ViewModel\OversizeViewModel;

class View
{
    /**
     * @var OversizeViewModel
     */
    protected $viewModel;

    public function __construct(OversizeViewModel $viewModel)
    {
        $this->viewModel = $viewModel;
    }

    /**
     * @param Subject $subject
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeToHtml(Subject $subject): array
    {
        $subject->assign('viewModel', $this->viewModel);

        return [];
    }
}
```

In this way, the view model will be added to this PHP class in the area where it is used in the layout file.

This method is also used to add the view model to the widgets.